# Customize Google Assistant button

Tags: buttons, motorola, google-assistant

I am using a Motorola phone which has a dedicated Google Assistant button, but I don't use the assistant much.

Is it possible to customize the button and use it for some other activity?

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately there is a way..

Download this [Button Mapper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=flar2.homebutton&hl=en_US) , grant the accessibility permission then click on add a button then press the button to record it and then set the function you want! Simple as that.

Remember to turn off battery optimization for Button Mapper app because if the app is paused by the battery optimization then no hardware buttons will work (touch screen will work). You'll have to go to settings and kill the Button Mapper app to get hardware buttons working again.

This is the only way to change the button function without root.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to customize the Google Assistant button, then [Assistant Shortcuts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=host.stjin.assistantshortcuts) is a good solution.

By setting it as the device's "assistant", you have a single button press to perform any function you specify. I'm currently using it to take screenshots.